# PHP - Loop through all records in table

Tags: php, mysql

Morning,

I have a table called `wp_cam_rules` which has two fields in it (two that i'm interested in) they are `rule_exclude_values` and `rule_include_values`. There are approx 100 entries in `wp_cam_rules`. `rule_exclude_values` and `rule_include_values` contain a comma separated list.

What I want to do is, using php, is loop through each of the rows and check some criteria.

Basically the function will take a string ($x), check if this string contains any of the exclude words (`rule_exclude_values`). If it doesn't then check if it contains any of the include words (`rule_include_values`) and print some text accordingly.

The problem I'm having at the minute is that code seems to be stopping after the first entry and not looping, please can anyone help?

Here's the code:

```
function get_attributes($x) {


$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_wcam_rules";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$attribute_results= array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$attribute_results[] = $row;

}

foreach ($attribute_results as $row) {

    $exclude_words = $row['rule_exclude_values'];
    $include_words = $row['rule_include_values'];

    foreach ($exclude_words as $exclude_value) {

        if ( stripos($x,$exclude_value)===false) {
            $skip_word = false;
        } else {
            $y.= 'Excluded: '.$exclude_value;
            $skip_word = true;
            break;
        }
}

if ($skip_word ===false) {
        foreach ($include_words as $include_value) {

            if (stripos($x,$include_value) !== false) {

                $y .= 'Attribute Found: '.$include_value;
                continue;
            }

        }   
}


return $y;
}
}
```

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Why do you make a while loop, put all rows inside it, and then loop through all rows again? Why don't you just take the while loop straight away?

Answer (score 1):

You have a too early `break` in your code
Also, you do not need to use this flag `$skip_word`...

Give a try with this code

```
<?php
function get_attributes($x) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_wcam_rules";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $attribute_results= array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $attribute_results[] = $row;
    }

    foreach ($attribute_results as $row) {
        $exclude_words = $row['rule_exclude_values'];
        $include_words = $row['rule_include_values'];

        $y = '';
        foreach ($exclude_words as $exclude_value) {
            $y.= 'Excluded: '.$exclude_value;
            foreach ($include_words as $include_value) {
                if (stripos($x,$include_value) !== false) {
                    $y .= 'Attribute Found: '.$include_value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $y;
}
```

Comment: (If u have some time to improve u can delete the outer foreach loop :).

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to use `explode` function

```
$exclude_words = explode(',', $row['rule_exclude_values']);
```